# Установка расширения curl на php

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache

для просмотра модулей которые могу установить пишу:

```
apt-cache search php5-
```

выпадает список, смотрю есть ли мой(php5-curl) в нем.
смотрю есть, пишу:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

мне выдает

```
Работа dpkg прервана, вы должны вручную запустить «sudo dpkg --configure -a» для устранения проблемы.
```

что от меня требуется тут сделать подскажите пожалуйста чтобы установился модуль, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Пробовали запустить `sudo dpkg --configure -a`?
Проблема тут не в cURL, а в менеджере пакетов.

Comment: да попробывал, он что там настраивал, потом еще раз ввел sudo apt-get install php5-curl, теперь вот висит окошко из надписью Настраивается пакет ttf-mscorefonts-installer , уже висит около 5ти минут

Comment: Всё будет хорошо) Но лучше apt-get install php5-curl

Comment: @GrayHoax я на это надеюсь))  но я и запустил apt-get install php5-curl после sudo dpkg --configure -a  и вижу то что вижу) а та надпись и продолжает висеть

Comment: *уже висит около 5ти минут* — скачиваются шрифты. это может быть долго: включить в пакет их нельзя из-за лицензионных ограничений со стороны `microsoft`, поэтому скачиваются через цепочку перенаправлений с их сайта.

Comment: не минусуйте автора ответа пожалуйста)) человек хоть начал уточнять что я делал.  @alexanderbarakin а как долго они могут качаться?

Comment: зависит от скорости канала, от работоспособности переадресовщиков, от хорошего настроения админов microsoft-овских серверов, и т.д. полчаса уже, кажется, прошло? если никакой информации не появляется, попробуйте остановить выполнение команды комбинацией `ctrl+c` и запустить её заново.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin нивкакую не ставиться, уже перезапускал 2 раза, ждал подолгу, можете еще что то порекомендовать?

Comment: остановите, обновите список пакетов (`$sudo apt-get update`) и попробуйте явно установить пакет: `$ sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer`.

Answer (score 0):

Когда я отписывал что идет настройка "Настраивается пакет ttf-mscorefonts-installer" и "висит" это окно, там была кнопка "Ok" которая была неактивной и которая не нажималась. Я думал что это нужно просто обождать.

Оказалось что нужно было перейти на эту кнопку из клавиатуры "пробелом" и нажать окей. 
После этого установка заняла минуту от силы.